# is it possible to remove the consul legacy servcie automatically

Tags: consul

I am using consul(`docker.io/bitnami/consul:1.10.2-debian-10-r0'`) as my register center, now I am facing a problem that the consul did not remove the dead service automatically. now my register center look like this:

[image]

is it possible to remove the dead legacy service automatically and make the register center always keep the lastest avaliable service snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

Consul does not automatically remove dead services (although it will remove dead nodes after 72 hours). You will need to deregister the instances from the catalog in order to remove the unhealthy service entries.

Comment: why the consul did not auto register the dead service? why design like this? @Blake Covarrubias

Comment: Consul does not automatically register services. All services must be manually registered, or at least synchronized from some third party program. How are you registering services to Consul in your environment?

Comment: I did not deregistered service by manual, that why my serivce list all dead service, I think the consul will manage service life cycle by default originally, now I think I am wrong. @Blake Covarrubias

Comment: I think it will be better to manage the service by consul .